# Using bash shell function inside AWK

Tags: bash, awk

Is it possible to use bash function inside AWK somehow?

Example file (string, int, int, int)

```
Mike 247808 247809 247810
```

Trying to convert values from decimal to hexadecimal.

Function defined either in `.bashrc` or in shell script.

```
$ awk '{print $1 ; d2h($2)}' file

awk: calling undefined function d2h
 input record number 1, file file
 source line number 1
```

Answer (score 47):

Try to use `system()` function:

```
awk '{printf("%s ",$1); system("d2h " $2)}' file
```

In your case `system` will call `d2h 247808` and then append output of this command to `printf` output:

```
Mike 3C800
```

EDIT:

As `system` uses `sh` instead of `bash` I can't find a way to access `.bashrc`. But you can still use functions from your current bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
d2h() {
    # do some cool conversion here
    echo "$1" # or just output the first parameter
}
export -f d2h
awk '{printf("%s ",$1); system("bash -c '\''d2h "$2"'\''")}' file
```

*Note: `-f` is used to [export a function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-export) rather than a variable.*

EDIT 2:

I don't know why, but this is not working on my Ubuntu 16.04. This is strange, because it used to work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This could work if `d2h` were an executable, but not if it's a "function defined either in .bashrc or in shell script".

Comment: @MichaelHomer yes, you are right. Thanks to your comment I realised I have answered the question nobody asked. But I have found a way to use functions from the current script (and possibly from other scripts via `source`) but I can'f figure out why it doesn't work with `.bashrc`.

Comment: That's also a command injection vulnerability as the content of `$2` ends up being interpreted as shell code.

Comment: If `export -f d2h` doesn't work, you can do it like for ksh/zsh :  
(\42 and \47 are the escape codes for simple and double quotes)

`CODE=$(typeset -f d2h) awk ' { system("bash -c \47eval \42$CODE\42; d2h \42"$2"\42\47") }' 
`

Answer (score 14):

You can call bash from awk and use its output. That is obviously dangerous from a performance perspective if it happens too often. Quoting the man page:

```
command | getline [var]
```

> Run command piping the output either into $0 or var,

command would be a bash script that contains the function definition and executes the function.

Comment: Documentation :https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe

Answer (score 7):

Converting from decimal to hexadecimal is something that `awk` can very well do itself. And you could define an *`awk`* function to do it:

```c
function d2h(d) {
  return sprintf("%x", d)
}
```

Now to answer the question in the general case, for `awk` to run `bash` functions, you'd need `awk` to execute a `bash` shell, that `bash` to interpret the definition of that function, and call that function, with the value extracted by `awk` passed as arguments.

Not trivial.

`bash` supports exporting functions via the environment, so it's available in subsequent invocations of `bash`, so that's one way to pass the definition of the function to the `bash` invoked by `awk`:

```
export -f d2h
```

The only ways for `awk` to execute a command (`bash` here) are with its `system("cmd")`, or `print... | "cmd"` or `"cmd" | getline`. In all cases, `awk` runs a shell to interpret that `cmd`, but it will be `sh`, not `bash`. So you need to construct a command line for `sh` that is a `bash` invocation that interprets a `bash` command line to invoke the function, so you need to be careful with quoting:

```
export -f d2h
<file awk -v q="'" '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  {print $1; system("exec bash -c '\''d2h \"$1\"'\'' bash " shquote($2))}'
```

If you want to get the output of the function back into `awk`, you'd need to transfer it back via a pipe. For that, you'd use `cmd | getline` instead of `system(cmd)` (which leaves `cmd`'s stdout untouched).

`cmd | getline line` stores *one line* (strictly speaking *one record*, records being lines by default), so to get the whole output in the cases where it's made of several lines, you'd need a loop such as:

```bsh
awk '...
  cmd = "exec bash -c '\''d2h \"$1\"'\'' bash " shquote($2)
  output = ""
  while ((cmd | getline line) > 0) {
    output = output line RS
  }
  sub(RS "$", "", output) # remove the last newline
  ...'
```

That does mean running one `sh` and one `bash` for each each invocation of the function, so is going to be quite inefficient. That would end up being even significantly more inefficient than having `bash` do the reading and splitting with a `while read loop`:

```
(unset -v IFS; while read -r a b rest; do
  printf '%s\n' "$a"
  d2h "$b"
 done < file)
```

Also note that since shellshock, `bash` now export functions in environment variables that are named like `BASH_FUNC_d2h%%`. Some `sh` implementations including `mksh` and newer versions of `dash` *remove* those environment variables  from the environment:

```
$ env 'foo%%=bar' dash -c 'printenv foo%%'
$ env 'foo%%=bar' mksh -c 'printenv foo%%'
$ env 'foo%%=bar' zsh  -c 'printenv foo%%'
bar
$ env 'foo%%=bar' bash -c 'printenv foo%%'
bar
```

So instead of relying on the flimsy function export feature, you could pass the function definition some other way. It could be via an environment variable with a usual name:

```bsh
BASH_FUNCTIONS=$(typeset -f d2h) awk '
   ...
   cmd = "exec bash -c '\''eval \"$BASH_FUNCTIONS\";" \
         "d2h \"$1\"'\'' bash " shquote($2)
   ...'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this :

```
awk '{print $1 ; printf "%x\n", $2}' file
```

AFAIK, you can't use a bash function in awk but only a script. You can use an awk function if needed.

Answer (score 5):

## Using a user defined bash function inside awk

*Disclaimer:* I realize this is not what the OP is trying to do, but Google will lead others like me to this answer.

### Situation

You have a `bash` script that is organized with functions (because you do not hate yourself or [most] coworkers) and at least 1 of those functions needs to call another from within `awk`.

### Solution

*Script*

```
#!/bin/env bash

# The main function - it's a sound pattern even in BASH
main(){
    # In the awk command I do some tricky things with single quotes. Count carefully...
    # The first $0 is outside the single quotes so it is the name of the current bash script.
    # The second $0 is inside the single quotes so it is awk's current line of input.
    awk '{printf("%s. ", ++c); system("'$0' --do"); print $0}'<<-PRETEND_THIS_IS_AN_INPUT_STREAM
        and
        and
        well
    PRETEND_THIS_IS_AN_INPUT_STREAM
}

# functionized to keep things DRY
doit(){
    echo -n "doin' it "
}


# check for a command switch and call different functionality if it is found
if [[ $# -eq 1 && $1 == "--do" ]];
then
        doit
else
        main
fi
```

*Output*

```
$ ./example.sh
1. doin' it and
2. doin' it and
3. doin' it well
```

Comment: I represent Queens, she was raised out in Brooklyn

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick example to demonstrate @HaukeLaging's `command|getline`  :

1. let input be:

```
Dear friends
my name is `id -nu` and
today is `date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.
```

where we are following shell syntax, in the input,

```
`command`
```

is used to denote *inline commands* to be replaced by the result of his execution.

2. We can expand inline shell command by:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN  { FS ="`";        }
NF==3  { $2 | getline $2 }
       { print           }
```

3. Usage (after the usual chmod ):

```
$ expand-inline input
Dear friends
my name is jjoao and
today is 2018-01-15.
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you good chances.

```
cat ../logs/em2.log.1 |grep -i 192.168.21.15 |awk '{system("date"); print $1}'
```

system function enables you to parse bash command within awk stream.

Answer (score 1):

This answer if for GNU awk, but other versions may implement the same trick. The idea is that as long as the right-hand side of the pipe is exactly the same and doesn't exit, awk doesn't close the pipe. But if it is different, it will open a new pipe. For instance, if you type:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ shell= "/bin/bash" } { print $0 | "/bin/bash" } END { print "echo $a" | " /bin/bash" }'
```

you can type:

```
a=5
echo $a
```

and get the expected (?) response 5: no new shell was spawned. But in the END section, I typed an extra space, so the RHS of the pipe is different, and a new shell is spawned with no value for variable a (and thus will print a blank line on exit. I cannot find it in the documentation, but the recommanded way of using long term pipes is as I have: put the command in the BEGIN section in a variable, and reuse that variable.

Giving a user-defined function to a bash session and then reusing it is an exercice left to the reader :)