# How can I call a bash function in bash script inside awk?

Tags: bash, awk, function

This issue is related to [Using bash shell function inside AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72935/using-bash-shell-function-inside-awk/156771#156771)

I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash

function emotion() {
            #here is function code end with return value...
            echo $1
}

export -f emotion

#I've put all animals in array
animalList=($(awk '{print $1}' animal.csv)) 

#loop  array and grep all the lines form the file
for j in ${animalList[@]}
do
  :                                                     #here I'am running a bash script calling emotion function 
   grep $j animal.csv | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){system("bash -c '\''emotion "$i"'\''")}}'
done
```

and I have this file:

```
cat    smile    happy   laugh
dog    angry    sad
mouse  happy    
wolf   sad      cry
fox    sleep    quiet
```

The output should like this:

```
smile
happy
laugh
angry
sad
happy    
sad
cry
sleep
quiet
```

The issue it tells me `bash: emotion: command not found`

According to akarilimano's comment [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156771/257479)

> this is not working on my Ubuntu 16.04. This is strange, because it used to work "on Ubuntu 14.04.

So how to do it in newer versions?

Comment: Why all this? Off the top of my head: `awk '{$1=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s\n", $i) }' yourfile` should get the desired result

Comment: Hmm, works for me as written with bash version `4.4.12` on arch linux. What are you running this on?

Comment: @val0x00ff I'm using a complex function in my code. I adjust the code in my question to make it simple

Comment: @krankry _Why_ do you want to use the complex function to do what looks like a very simple operation?

Comment: @Kusalananda There an if statement in the function has many options. It should call a url and extract some info from each emotion, and get the max value, to do more operation with the max value, and return. That's why I'm using function. I have not wrote the whole function because it's useless in the question

Comment: @krankry Since the function is irrelevant to the question as it is written now, val0x00ff's comment is the correct solution to produce the expected output. [Edit] the question to make the use of the function relevant.

Comment: @Michael Daffin 4.13.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's probably not the best way to approach the problem.

From `awk`, all you can do is build a command line that `system()` passes to `sh`. So, you need the arguments to be formatted in the `sh` syntax.

So you'd need:

```
emotion() {
  echo "$i"
}
export -f emotion
awk -v q="'" '
  function sh_quote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
      status = system("bash -c '\''emotion \"$@\"'\'' bash " sh_quote($1)
  }'
```

Here quoting awk's `$1` so it can be safely embedded in the `sh` command line that ends up running `bash` with the content of `$1` as last argument, which then passes it to `emotion`.

That assumes your `sh` and your `awk` don't strip the special environment variables that `bash` uses to export functions (like `pdksh` and derivatives (such as `mksh`) do for instance, [or `dash` since 0.5.8 which explains your 14.04 vs 16.04 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38079864)), and that your distribution has not disabled exported functions in `bash`.

If it does, you could do it like for `ksh`/`zsh`, and pass the definition of the function some other way, like:

```
CODE=$(typeset -f emotion) awk -v q="'" '
  function sh_quote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
      status = system("bash -c '\''eval \"$CODE\"; emotion \"$@\"'\'' bash " \
                      sh_quote($1)
  }'
```

In both cases, that means running one sh and one bash for it. Maybe you can pass the `$i` to `bash` some other way than via a `system()` that executes two instances of a shell each time. Like:

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s\0" $i}' |
  while IFS= read -r i; do
    emotion "$i"
  done
```

Or do the word splitting in `bash` directly:

```
unset IFS
while read -ra fields; do
  for i in "${fields[@]:1}"; do
    emotion "$i"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not work on Ubuntu 16.04 because `/bin/sh` is linked to the `dash` shell, whereas on Ubuntu 14.04 `/bin/sh` is linked to the `bash` shell.  Why does this matter?  Awk's `system()` function uses `/bin/sh` and therefore invokes the `dash` shell on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: dash is sh by default on 14.04 as well. The difference is that since 0.5.8, dash sanitizes its environment, so removes the `BASH_FUNC_emotion%%` variable (the new variable names since shellshock) from it as it doesn't consider it a valid variable name. mksh does that as well. Other shells don't in my tests.

Comment: Not on all Ubuntu 14.04.   For example, OOTB, `bash` was the default shell on the initial Linux Subsystem for Windows 10 Anniversary edition.