# How to run bash commands from within awk?

Tags: awk

Is there any way to run bash commands from within awk?

I want to use 'read' command inside awk but it's not working. Is there any workaround?

Comment: you can't use read inside awk if it already piped, if not, then `{}` doing the same,  also `system()` can run command

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Would `awk`'s own `getline` help? Or are you trying to do something interactive?

Comment: this will read output of ls to a
`awk 'BEGIN{"ls" |& getline a;print a}'`

Comment: @Kusalananda I want the solution for any command and not just for read

Comment: @KishanKumar can you create a little sample with your trouble ? As I shown above - you can easy run command, what you want from it ?

Comment: XY problem. Please describe your task, and ignore the technology you think you need to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using bash shell function inside AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72935/using-bash-shell-function-inside-awk)

Answer (score 0):

```
# gawk 'BEGIN {system("touch /tmp/aaaa")}'
# ls /tmp/aaaa
/tmp/aaaa
```